# elasticsearch search results with sub query

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting started with elasticsearch, not sure if this is possible with one query along with pagination.  I have a index with two types: `user` & `blog`. Example mapping:

```
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "properties": {
             "name" : { "type": "string" }
         }
      },
      "blog": {
         "properties": {
             "title" : { "type": "string" },
             "author_name" : { "type": "string" }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

sample data

user:

```
[
    {"name": "jemmy"},
    {"name": "Tom"}
]
```

blog:

```
[
    {"title": "foo bar", "author": "jemmy"},
    {"title": "magic foo", "author": "Tom"},
    {"title": "bigdata for dummies", "author": "Tom"},
    {"title": "elasticsearch", "author": "Tom"},
    {"title": "JS cookbook", "author": "jemmy"},
]
```

I'd like to query on the index such a way that when I search for `blog` it should do subquery on on each match. For example:

```
POST /test_index/blog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

Expected (pseudo) results:

```
[
  {
      title: "foo bar",
      author_name: "Jemmy",
      author_post_count: 2
  },
  {
      title: "magic foo",
      author_name: "Tom",
      author_post_count: 3
  }
]
```

Here `author_post_count` is `blog` post count that the user has authored. If it could return those blog posts instead of count that would be great too. Is this possible? Perhaps the term i'm using not right, but I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I don't think I understand the requirement. You mention aggregation, but I see no such thing in your query sample. Also, maybe it's better if you provide some document examples, what you want to match and how should the result look like for those examples.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've updated the question. Perhaps aggregation is the wrong term here. Also, the query sample is the match portion. My question is how to populate  `author_post_count` in the resultset

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
POST /test_index/blog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "foo"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counting_posts": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "authors": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "author",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Be careful though with `terms` aggregation because it is considering the actual tokenized list of terms from the index, not what you actually index (lowercase/uppercase, tokenized in a way or another).